# MSYS - PyAudio Greek letters

Tags: python, encoding, pyaudio, msys

MSYS PyAudio module:

```
counter = 1
for i in range (0,self.numdevices):
    if self.p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0,i).get('maxOutputChannels')>0:
        self.output_devices.append([counter,i,str(self.p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0,i).get('name'))])
        counter += 1
```

If greek letters are in path there aren't displayed correctly.

[image]

Code:

```
Χρήστος@Chris-pc MINGW64 /c/python/scripts/Papinhio player/src/main/python_files
$ python
Python 3.8.9 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:54:59)  [GCC 10.2.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on wi
n32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyaudio
>>> p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
>>> info = p.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)
>>> numdevices = info.get('deviceCount')
>>> for i in range(0,numdevices):
...     print(p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0,i).get('name'))
...
Microsoft Sound Mapper - Input
Ìéêñüöùíï (FHD Webcam)
Microsoft Sound Mapper - Output
Ç÷åßá / ÁêïõóôéêÜ (Realtek High
>>> for i in range(0,numdevices):                                      '))
...     print(p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0,i))       )))))
...
{'index': 0, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'Microsoft Sound Mapper - Input', 'host
Api': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 2, 'maxOutputChannels': 0, 'defaultLowInputLatency'
: 0.09, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.09, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.18, 'defau
ltHighOutputLatency': 0.18, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
{'index': 1, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'Ìéêñüöùíï (FHD Webcam)', 'hostApi': 0,
 'maxInputChannels': 2, 'maxOutputChannels': 0, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.09,
'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.09, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.18, 'defaultHighOu
tputLatency': 0.18, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
{'index': 2, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'Microsoft Sound Mapper - Output', 'hos
tApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 0, 'maxOutputChannels': 2, 'defaultLowInputLatency
': 0.09, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.09, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.18, 'defa
ultHighOutputLatency': 0.18, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
{'index': 3, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'Ç÷åßá / ÁêïõóôéêÜ (Realtek High', 'hos
tApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 0, 'maxOutputChannels': 2, 'defaultLowInputLatency
': 0.09, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.09, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.18, 'defa
ultHighOutputLatency': 0.18, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
```

Comment: once question per post.

Comment: Ok, but i think it's the same problem.

Comment: I recommend you minimize the problem since there are 2 different libraries: 1) Verify that the library that obtains the letters reads it with the correct encoding and after fixing that bug then you just analyze if the problem spreads to Qt. Maybe the problem has nothing to do with Qt and just including it adds unnecessary complexity

Comment: @eyllanesc i found the solution in the second part of the question (which is deleted now): 1) i set windows enviroment variable: set `MSYS=enable_pcon` 2) I add imageformats directory in   `self.app.addLibraryPath(r"C:/Python/Lib/site-packages/qt5_applications/Qt/plugins/imageformats")
` (note that the above path is not from python installed in msys but from python 3.9 which is installed directly in windows , but all of that doesn't solve the pyaudio device encoding error.

Comment: @eyllanesc code added.

Comment: Windows strings are Unicode, since Windows NT came out in 1994. Python 3 strings are Unicode. What you posted though is ASCII text displayed using the wrong codepage. There are too many things mixed up in this question to say what caused this. Obviously Windows applications have no such issues. Python 3 on Windows has no issues. Python 3 on WSL has no issues. You're using MINGW though and the screenshot you posted is *not* a Windows dialog

Answer (score 0):

I change line 994 of `C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.8\site-packages\PyAudio-0.2.11-py3.8-mingw.egg\pyaudio.py`

from

```
for codec in ["utf-8", "cp1252"]:
```

to be:

```
for codec in ["cp1253", "cp1252", "utf-8"]:
```

Comment: That didn't fix the problem. Τα Windows δεν έχουν πρόβλημα με τα ελληνικά. The problem is the use of ASCII codepages to begin with. StackOverflow runs on Windows, and yet I had no problem typing Greek text. And given that Python 3 uses Unicode, those hard-coded codepages *cause* problems, they don't solve them. There's shouldn't be any need even for `for codec in ["utf-8", "cp1252"]:`. `utf-8` isn't needed when strings are already Unicode. And when reading non-Unicode text, one can't assume it's Latin1

Comment: Are you using an ASCII version of PortAudio perhaps? Or compiled the libraries for ASCII instead of Unicode?

Comment: I used that: `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-portaudio` , `https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz`